# Measure page load and iframe load

Tags: javascript, html, performance, iframe, pageload

Basically I have a webpage and inside it I have an iframe to load another webpage from a different domain. It moves slow and I want to prove that the entire page is slow just because of the page inside the iframe.

Is there any way to measure what is the overall page load and how much % from that total comes from the iframe ? What tools I can use to obtain some measurements?

Answer (score 1):

You can measure in the **Chrome browser** 
go to **[Inspect Element -> Performance]** and also **[Inspect Element -> Network]** and reload page to get full details

Comment: How to differentiate between the entire page and the iframe? How to know when the iframe begun to load and how much it took ?

Comment: It will inspect all elements in the page. for example in the sample image you can see fav-icon timing on load and traffic usage. https://image.ibb.co/b8tLcy/2018_06_13_11_13_18.jpg

Comment: It starts from 380.73 ms and used 27.17 ms to completely load

Comment: It says queued 300ms, started 700ms, what's the difference between them ? I thought that when it's queued it will start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you would have posted your website here. However, you could try running a PageSpeed insights test here using Google's PageSpeed Insights tool -https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

You could also use the Chrome browser extension called Lighthouse:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk